# Define a constant in karate-netty

Tags: karate

If I would to do something like:

```
Feature: Register the account and obtain the jwt

Background:
* url baseUrl
* def email = 'qatest_api_' + String(new Date().getTime()) + '@redacted.com'

Scenario: Register

Given path '/identity/v1/register'
  * request {email: '#(email)', password: '#(password)'}
When method post
Then status 200

Scenario: Obtain jwt

Given url 'https://redacted/oauth/token'
  * request 
"""
  {
    realm: "Username-Password-Authentication",
    grant_type: "http://auth0.com/oauth/grant-type/password-realm",
    username: '#(email)',
    password: '#(password)',
    audience: "https://redacted/userinfo",
    scope: "openid",
    client_id: "redacted",
    client_secret: "redacted"
  }
"""
When method post
Then status 200
```

It would evaluate `email` variable on both scenarios, so on one I get something like `qatest_api_1542209546879@redacted.com` on 1st scenario and `qatest_api_1542209545312@redacted.com` on 2nd scenario.

I would evade hardcoding this value if possible, I read about `callonce` but didnt use it, it sounds funny to have a standalone file for generating time stamp.

Im using karate-netty, do you have suggestions on how to achieve this? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callonce` is designed so that it can be javascript on the right-hand-side.

Try this in the `Background`:

```
* def fun = function(){ return 'qatest_api_' + new Date().getTime() + '@redacted.com' }
* def email = callonce fun
```

The advantage of having a second file is that it can be re-used in multiple scenarios, there is nothing wrong with it :)

Comment: works like a charm, thanks for quick answer with jedi precision <3